# What's the crystal orbital Hamiltonian population?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, density-of-states

What's the crystal orbital Hamiltonian population (COHP) or the crystal orbital overlap population (COOP)? What's the relation between the bandstructure or density of states (DOS) and COHP/COOP? Why we can read the information about bonding or antibonding information from COHP and COOP?

A clear physical picture will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like these are discussed in https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4352/8/5/225

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now, but a good summary with references is here (from the creators of the LOBSTER code for COHP calculations): http://schmeling.ac.rwth-aachen.de/cohp/index.php?menuID=2textID=2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great description given of COOP in Roald Hoffman's [Solids and Surfaces: A Chemist's View of Bonding in Extended Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471187100). It is sometimes referred to as the Overlap Population Weighted Density of States (OPWDOS) which makes the meaning a bit clearer: its the density of states, weighted by the overlap for a given bond ($c_ic_jS_{ij}$). This results in a signed DOS, as the overlap population can be positive or negative. This quantity is similar (though not exactly equivalent) to the molecular concept of bond order, where a positive COOP denotes a favorable/bonding interaction and a negative COOP indicates an unfavorable/antibonding interaction. We can see an example of this below from Hoffman's book, giving an example for a simple hydrogen chain.

[image: COOP plot of H atom chain]

COHP, as mentioned in Kevin J.M.'s [link](http://schmeling.ac.rwth-aachen.de/cohp/index.php?menuID=2textID=2) is a variation on the same concept, where the weighting is now done based on off-diagonal Hamiltonian elements as opposed to off-diagonal overlap elements. There are apparently advantages to describing binding this way, but I haven't gotten to look at the [original COHP paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100135a014) to see why it is better than COOP. One difference to look out for is the COHP plots are generally actually -COHP to make them more comparable with COOP plots. This is because a negative Hamiltonian element would correspond to a favorable interaction.